# how to calculate derivatives of integer valued functions?

Tags: calculus

**Definitions:**

1. $[x]$ is the integer value of $x$. For example: $[4.3]=4$.
2. $\{x\}=x-[x]$.

Can someone help me calculate the derivative of the following functions, and determine where the derivative are not defined?

1. $[x^2]\sin^2(\pi x)$
2. $\{x^2\}\sin^2(\pi x)$

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

For the first one:

Consider 2 intervals $ A = [ \sqrt n, \sqrt{n+1} )$ and $ B = [ \sqrt {n+1}, \sqrt{n+2} )$. Of course, $n$ is an integer.

Now, in the first interval, your function becomes $ n\sin^2(\pi x) $. It's derivative is $ n\pi\sin(2\pi x) $. Call it $ f'_1(x) $.

Consider the second interval. Your function becomes $ (n+1)\sin^2(\pi x) $. It's derivative is $ (n+1)\pi\sin(2\pi x) $. Call it $ f'_2(x) $

Clearly it is differentiable *within* each interval. We now have to check if it is differentiable even at the point $ x = \sqrt {n+1} $.

For that, we must have $ \lim _{x\to(\sqrt{n+1})^-} f'_1(x) = \lim _{x\to(\sqrt{n+1})^+} f'_2(x) $.

That is, we must have: 
$ n\pi\sin(2\pi \sqrt{n+1}) = (n+1)\pi\sin(2\pi \sqrt{n+1}) $

Which will be true when $ \sqrt{n+1} $ is an integer. In other words, it is differentiable when $n+1$ is a perfect square.

---

So, your function is differentiable everywhere, except at those integers which are not perfect squares. Note, here our intervals consisted only of positive integers, but a simple sign change will give the same result for negative integers.

I think the same logic can be applied to the second function.

Comment: Ok I'll try that . Thaks!

Answer (score 0):

Derivate Fourier expansion

$$\{x\}= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)} {k}$$

Comment: Nice :) I'll try that. Thanks!